# Android TTS from multiple Activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to make sparing use of TTS from several Activities (one MAIN Activity can start multiple other Activities).

I realize that there is no concept of a "global" class (or any other global anything), other than via Application and `Activity.getApplication()`. It is all but useless since it returns `null` in an Activity's `onCreate()` methods, or constructors. This appears to be because the Activity is not "attached" to the Application context until the object is completely constructed.

There MUST to be a way to do this that isn't full-on silly, like re-implementing TTS in each and every Activity.

Alternative: I use Intent and `startActivity()` to start each new Activity, so is there a way to pass a reference to the toplevel Activity via `Intent.putExtras()`?

Comment: Are you just calling a function/method?  If so, there is no reason why you shouldn't be able to either use `Application` or create a class that you can import.

Comment: I'm trying to grab a reference to the Application instance so that I can reuse its methods. This would result in one app-wide implementation of TTS, grabbed-settings, and lat/long positioning. But that doesn't work from onCreate(): getApplication returns null.

Comment: Current workaround: re-implement TTS and GPS in each Activity, and pass configuration data via Intent.putExtras(). So far, this is the only major glitch in Android architecture that I've stubbed my toe on. It's a big glitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextToSpeech` is tied to a `Context` (Activity), so you can't really make a 'global' object you can just use anywhere. If you don't want to duplicate code, create an base `TtsActivity` and put common code there. Or, create a `TtsManager` or similar class that takes care of initializing, etc. TTS and put it in all activities that need it.

Answer (score 0):

`getApplication()` always returns a valid reference if called from within your activity's `onCreate()` method. It will return `null` if called within the activity's constructor, but you shouldn't define a constructor for an activity anyway. Are you trying to call `onCreate()` yourself?

If you want to store data in the `Application` instance then you will need to subclass `Application` and you will need to provide the name of your subclass in the manifest as

```
<application android:name="fully.qualified.name.of.my.application.subclass">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a regular Java class that inherits from Object, and put the methods you want in there.

**Edit:**
I've never used android TTS, but it should look something like this, I'd gather

```
public class SpeechHelper {

   public static void speak(String text, Context con)
   {
        TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(con, TextToSpeech.onInitListener {
             private void onInit(int status){
                 tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, new HashMap<String, String>());
             }
        });
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of initiating Android TTS from an Object subclass?

Comment: posted a overly simplified example. You'd probably want to make this class static, take care of calling shutdown, and be able to set options on it.

Comment: Initializing `TextToSpeech` can take some time and doing this each time you want to `speak()` something is hardly a good idea.